# How to add auto layout constraints to UINavigationBar programmatically

Tags: ios

`UINavigationBar` suppose to appear on the top of view controller. It's not appearing. I am adding constraints with view.

**Code:**

```
  navBar=[[UINavigationBar alloc]init];
  [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.view  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:navBar attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:1.0 constant:10]];

  [navBar setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];

  [views addSubview:navBar];
```

Is there any problem in adding constraints?

Comment: You cannot use autolayoutconstraints with UINavigationBar. Consider subclassing UINavigationBar class

Comment: So how I will add UINavigationBar if I am not using any  frame method.@GeneratorOfOne

Comment: Just use methods on UINavigationBar self.leftBarButtonItem, self.rightBarButtonItem or self.titleView.

Comment: The easiest way to add a NavigationBar i using an `UINavigationController`.

Answer (score -1):

You can programmatically set layout constraints for a UINavgationBar, your constraint that you set is not correct.

You set:

self.view.top = navBar.NotAnAttribute * 1.0 (multiplier) + 10.0 (constant)

In my opinion this should be:

self.view.top = navBar.top * 1.0 + 10.0

therefore:

```
[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.view  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:navBar attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1.0 constant:10]];
```

should work.